# How to install and active SOAP in php 5.6

Tags: php, web-services, soap, ubuntu-16.04, php-5.6

When I typed `apt-cache search php | grep -i soap` in command line it says

```
libnusoap-php - SOAP toolkit for PHP
php7.0-soap - SOAP module for PHP
python-pysimplesoap - simple and lightweight SOAP Library (Python 2)
python3-pysimplesoap - simple and lightweight SOAP Library (Python 3)
php-soap - SOAP module for PHP [default]
php5.6-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.1-soap - SOAP module for PHP
php7.2-soap - SOAP module for PHP
root@ip-172-30-0-48:/var/www/html# sudo apt-get install php-soap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-soap is already the newest version (1:7.1+55+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libcurl3
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
```

===========

But SOAP is not active. Please help to start it..

Answer (score 0):

For PHP5.6, please run command

```
yum install php56w-soap
```

Please restart the service after installation

```
service httpd restart
```